# Wire in two lights to a switch plus a fan to a switch when power is coming in between the lights without using 14-3 wire

Tags: wiring, bathroom

I am redoing some work in my bathroom. I have a hot wire running between two lights with the switch outside one of the lights. How do I wire it with 14-2 wire without running the power source to one of the lights first? I also must use this same power source for a fan where the hot goes into the fan and then down to the switch.

Comment: In case you "accidentally" type something in all caps, there are online converters that are here [to help](http://convertcase.net/).

Answer (score 1):

They make products specifically for that problem.  You wire hot, neutral and ground to every location (i.e. 14/2 wire) and the switch, lamp controller and fan controller uses digital signaling to send the on/off command over the 14/2 or wirelessly.  Some can also be controlled by your smartphone etc.